# yii2 в папке на сайте

Tags: php, yii2

Имеется основной сайт `site.ru`. В каталоге `lk` я развернул yii2 advanced, теперь хочу, чтобы по адресу `site.ru/lk` открывался `frontend`, а по адресу `site.ru/lk/admin` открывался `backend`, с frontand разобрался, работает как нужно, а вот в backend попасть не могу, 404 not found.
.htacces в папке lk (корневая для yii2):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # если /admin, то в backend
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
    RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|js|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
    RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images)
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

backend/web/.htacces:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

frontend/config/main.php

```
 ....
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        'baseUrl' => '/lk',
    ],
....
```

backend/config/main.php

```
 ....
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        'baseUrl' => '/admin',
        // 'baseUrl' => 'lk/admin',
        // 'baseUrl' => '/lk/admin',
    ],
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогли ребята с https://yiiframework.ru/

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # если /admin, то в backend
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(lk/admin)
    RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|js|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(lk/admin)
    RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images)
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

backend/config/main.php:

```
 ....
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        'baseUrl' => '/lk/admin',
    ],
....
```